# Will numerical relativity figure into either the phenomenology of quantum gravity or the construction of the theory?

Tags: general-relativity, quantum-gravity

It appears as though we want to preserve, in a theory of quantum gravity, the empirical data that GR has led to. Given that much of that (e.g., the late merger for a binary black hole coalescence) is given by numerical relativity and other frameworks, will such frameworks be used for probing or constructing quantum gravity?

Comment: What do you mean by 'numerical relativity' here? Does it refer to computational models or something else?

Comment: I would guess it does refer to computational models.  In what other context is the term numerical relativity used?